# unable to remove google play store search history

Tags: search, search-history

I see the list of internet word searches every I go to google play. No matter what settings I use the words are still there. Show searches I made on the device. But only in google playstore. It could become embarrassing. I cleared data for all application I could find use history and cache cleaners. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instructions listed [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/465?source=gsearch).  On Android:

> *Tip:* If you want to delete your recent searches under the search box, touch and hold the search you want to delete **> OK**. The search will be deleted from the Google app and your Web & App Activity.
>
> **Delete items one at a time**
>
> 1. Visit your [Web & App Activity page](https://history.google.com/history/).
> 2. Check the box next to the items you want to remove.
> 3. Touch **Remove items** at the top of the page.
>
> **Delete multiple**
>
> 1. Visit your [Web & App Activity page](https://history.google.com/history/).
> 2. In the top right corner of the page, touch Options **> Remove items**.
> 3. Choose the time period for which you want to delete your history. (To remove all items, select **The beginning of time**).
> 4. Touch **Remove**.
>
> Note: If you turned on the option to include history from Chrome and other apps in your Web & App Activity, visit the [additional Web & App Activity page](https://history.google.com/history/app) to see that information. If you only want to remove additional Web & App Activity from a certain device, choose that device in the "Remove items" dropdown menu.